# Web-service technologies cross domain

Tags: c#, html, json, web-services, cross-domain

Recently I've been trying to implement a web service. I started off trying to use the "Web API" technology in C#.

The end goal is to have a web service that connects to a SQL-Server database and can be called by other sites, sat on different domains.

The web service takes the request, connects to the database and serves back HTML (can be as a string inside a JSON object...etc). The client site then displays this HTML, gets input from the user and then sends this data back to the web service to save in the database.

There seems to be a problem with "Web API" when the calls are cross domain. The same-origin policy prevents us calling Cross-Domain. I have read into CORS, but believe it is not compatible with IE8, which is a big blocker for us.

Most of my knowledge and all of our sites are ASP.net C#.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the problem with Web API? seems to be a problem is not a problem.

Comment: Sorry, I believe it's because of same-origin policy. I've read a little about CORS, but am not fully familiar with it. I believe it's not compatible with IE8, which is a big blocker for us.

Comment: Web API not compatible with IE8?

Comment: CORS not compatible with IE8.

Comment: your request is get or post? you can use jsonp for get.

Comment: How would I implement this? Also the client site would have to request the data, there would have to be 2 way communication.

Comment: Have a look at this link http://mcgivery.com/ie8-and-cors/ . This might be helpful

Comment: check my answer for a sample ajax call. but this would only work in case of get. For post you would have to implement CORS.

Comment: CORS has partial support in IE8 via XDomainRequest.

Comment: Hi Ray, I've looked at that just, but it seems you have to define the domain that will be contacting it. We will have multiple and more could be added all the time, so I'm not sure it's right for what I need. I'm currently looking into WCF.

Comment: @Tom.Bowen89 I'm not sure what you mean by "define the domain".  Sending a cross-domain request in IE8 or IE9 is not very different than sending a same-origin ajax request.  The API is the same, but there are a few restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've resolved our issue by using a WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use `Web API` , but to allow cross domain calls to web service you may try adding it to the `web.config` file.It will allow HTTP GET / POST requests

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
     <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
     </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

SAMPLE REQUEST:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://yoururl",
            type: "GET",
            data: "yourdata",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (response) {
                 //do something;
            }
        });
```